# How can I serve GZIP-encoded images from Google App Engine

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to get link sharing to include pictures on Facebook. The Facebook share debugger says the images are not being encoded with gzip, which is apparently a requirement.

Using curl, I'm able to confirm what Facebook is saying. All the docs I can find say that gzip encoding should happen automatically, so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Here's the curl output:

```
$ curl -v -D /tmp/h -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://m.kaon.com/ss/5907657076506624.jpg > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 172.217.3.115...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to m.kaon.com (172.217.3.115) port 80 (#0)
> GET /ss/5907657076506624.jpg HTTP/1.1
> Host: m.kaon.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 5b0c467df46cb34732e5721733742742
< Date: Wed, 13 Mar 2019 15:11:08 GMT
< Server: Google Frontend
< Content-Length: 128384
< 
{ [3516 bytes data]
100  125k  100  125k    0     0   620k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  623k
* Connection #0 to host m.kaon.com left intact
$ cat /tmp/h
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 5b0c467df46cb34732e5721733742742
Date: Wed, 13 Mar 2019 15:11:08 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 128384
```

And here's the code that serves the image:

```
class SSHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, id):
    a = ScreenShotModel.get_by_id(int(id))
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    self.response.out.write(a.image)
```

Is there some app.yaml setting I'm missing, or perhaps I need to add something else to the headers? Or should I be looking for the accept-encoding header myself and doing the gzip in my python code?

Comment: Did you try adding to your code `self.response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'`, to add to the header the type of encoding?

Comment: That would be very surprising if it worked. Anyway, I tried it, and it didn't change anything. In fact, GAE stripped it out. GAE doesn't let you set the content-encoding header. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference/request-response-headers

Comment: Facebook spontaneously started accepting my non-gzip'd images, so I guess I don't need this answered. But I'm still curious about it, if anyone knows the answer.

Answer (score -1):

It does not make sense to gzip a jpeg. It is already compressed.

There’s a set of allowed mime types for compression. JPEG is not one of them.

The typical ones in the whitelist are:

text/plain, text/html, application/javascript, etc

Comment: JPEG is compressed on a block-by-block basis and in fact, GZIP of a JPEG will often produce much smaller files because there are similarities between blocks. It is perfectly valid to want to GZIP a JPEG, and it's weird that GAE doesn't seem to allow it.